# MVC Razor string.format in html.raw

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I use this razor code to generate a HTML button that calls a function with a value from the model:

```
Html.Raw(string.Format("<button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-xs' onclick='setCoordinatorForService('{0}')'>Åta</button>", item.Name))
```

The value of item.Name is "abc", the code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="setCoordinatorForService(" abc')'="">Åta</button>
```

I want this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="setCoordinatorForService("abc")'="">Åta</button>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How about `setCoordinatorForService(\"{0}\")`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must replace ' to \"

If you use this code, probably it works very well.

```
Html.Raw(string.Format("<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-xs\" onclick=\"setCoordinatorForService('{0}')\">Åta</button>", item.Name)))
```

Besides the line you wanted it has error.

```
onclick="setCoordinatorForService("abc")'=""
```

part maybe give an error because of =